# What is an exact explanation of concept of hyperfunction been given by Mikio Sato?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In *An elementary theory of hyperfunctions and microfunctions* by Hikosaburo Komatsu, it says:

> The hyperfunctions in the higher dimensional case have the same properties, and are characterized by them, too. It was not easy, however, to define the spaces $\mathcal B(\Omega), \Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, of hyperfunctions having these properties. Sato had spent two years before he succeeded in giving a definition for the higher dimensional case. His definition is $$\mathcal B(\Omega) = H^n(V, V\setminus \Omega; \mathcal O).$$

M. Sato's definition of hyperfunctions can be found [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp27/bcp27122.pdf). See (1.9).

My question is regarding the definition provided by Komatsu. What is the $n$th relative cohomology group of the open pair $(V,V/\Omega)$?

Comment: Is that [relative sheaf cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_cohomology#Relative_cohomology)?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: You may also take a look at http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1973__2-3__252_0.pdf . See  1. Hyperfunctions